# Gdb pretty printer is not working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, gcc, gdb

I have debugged C++ codes using gdb in Ubuntu 14.04. When I pass a stl container to the print command, it used to print the contents of the container. But then I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS a week back. Now those pretty printers are not working. When I print them I get those raw container output you get when you don't have python printers installed.

I have `libstdcxx/v6/python.py` on my system. I also have `libstdc++.so.6.0.21-gdb.py` in the auto-load folder. When I print info pretty-printer in gdb, I get a list of stl printers, so I know they are registered. However, my `gdb` doesn't print `std::list` variable. I have enabled pretty-printer, set print pretty on.

My `gcc` version is 5.4 and `gdb` version is 7.11.1.Both were installed along with Ubuntu 16.04. I haven't built them manually. So anything obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that with newer libstdcxx, containers (some of them?) are moved to the std::__cxx11:: name space and existing pattern matching of the existing pretty-printer no longer matches.   Following patch adds that pattern and fixed it for me.

```
*** /usr/share/gcc-5/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py.orig       2016-08-08 16:49:58.000000000 +0000                                                                     
--- /usr/share/gcc-5/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py    2016-11-08 23:25:23.620557354 +0000                                                                             
***************
*** 1081,1086 ****
--- 1081,1087 ----
      def add_container(self, base, name, function):                                                                                                                    
          self.add_version(base, name, function)                                                                                                                        
          self.add_version(base + '__cxx1998::', name, function)                                                                                                        
+         self.add_version(base + '__cxx11::', name, function)                                                                                                          

      @staticmethod                                                                                                                                                     
      def get_basic_type(type):
```